# How do you view <abbr> tags on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, tags, abbr

We often use the `<abbr>` tag in *HTML* like this

```
<abbr title="Laugh Out Loud">LOL</abbr>
```

When on PC, we hover our mouse long enough on **LOL** and the *Laugh Out Loud* tooltip(kinda thing) shows up. What do we do on PHONES to see the ***title*** of the `<abbr>` tag? Like, do we touch and hold, do we double-tap (None of these work, I've tried)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the mobile devices won't display the tooltip when an user touches the text, but it can be modified by using CSS pseudo element properties. check out the link below:

[Making the abbr element work for touchscreen, keyboard, and mouse](https://bitsofco.de/making-abbr-work-for-touchscreen-keyboard-mouse/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to your css:

```
abbr::after{ /* or ::before */
    content: ' (' attr(title) ') ';
}
```